# R AzureTableStor package: How to update an Azure Table

Tags: r, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to update a newly created Azure table with the data from a data frame in R.

My table is super simple and always has one row: every time I run the script I would like to update the Azure Table by adding the new row to create a history log.

This is my data frame:

```
Teams_Service_Status <- data.frame(
                               service = "Microsoft Teams", 
                               status = "serviceDegradation", 
                               id = "Microsoft Teams", 
                               timestamp = "2022-05-02 10:20:55"
                        )
```

This is my code:

```
TSS_Endpoint <- table_endpoint ("https://mystorageaccount.table.core.windows.net/", key = "mykey")
list_storage_tables(TSS_Endpoint)
entities <- colnames(Teams_Service_Status)
teamsservicestatus <- storage_table(TSS_Endpoint, "teamservicestatus") %>% 
                                                                  import_table_entities(
                                                                                   Teams_Service_Status,
                                                                                   entities,
                                                                                   row_key = row.names(Teams_Service_Status), 
                                                                                   partition_key = as.character(Teams_Service_Status$timestamp)
                                                                                        )
```

When I run the code, I can see the list of tables in my storage account:

```
$teamsservicestatus
Azure table 'teamsservicestatus'
URL: https://mystorageaccount.table.core.windows.net/teamsservicestatus
Access key: <hidden>
Azure Active Directory access token: <none supplied>
Account shared access signature: <none supplied>
Storage API version: 2020-10-02
```

The issue seems to be when I run the last part of the script:

```
> teamsservicestatus <- storage_table(TSS_Endpoint, "teamservicestatus") %>% 
+                                                                   import_table_entities(
+                                                                                    Teams_Service_Status,
+                                                                                    entities,
+                                                                                    row_key = row.names(Teams_Service_Status), 
+                                                                                    partition_key = as.character(Teams_Service_Status$timestamp)
+                                                                                         )
Error in match.arg(batch_status_handler) : 'arg' must be of length 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

~

Answer (score 2):

Just to let you know that I resolved it. I was adding an extra step that wasn't needed. See below the code that works!

```
TSS_Endpoint <- table_endpoint ("https://mystoragetable.table.core.windows.net/", key = "mykey")
list_storage_tables(TSS_Endpoint)
Table <- storage_table(TSS_Endpoint, "teamsservicestatus")
RowKey <- row.names(Teams_Service_Status)
PartitionKey <- as.character(Teams_Service_Status$service)


TeamsServiceStatus <- import_table_entities(
                                            Table,
                                            Teams_Service_Status,
                                            row_key = RowKey, 
                                            partition_key = PartitionKey
                                            )
list_table_entities(Table)
```